# How to replace query parameters into intercalated url?

Tags: asp.net-core, url, query-string

Hello i am want to know given a an url saved as a string with placeholders.Is there anyway to just replace the spaceholders with the desired values?

```
public string Constant= @"/main/url/[id]/something/[value]";

public string Replace(int id,string value)
{
  string url=Replace(id,value,Constant); // "/main/url/3/something/abc"
}
```

As you can see the url is intercalated with variables.Is there any class provided by the framework that i could use like:

```
public class Replacer
{

   public string FillUrl(List<object> variables,string url)
   {
        var fullUrl=Replace(variables,url); 
        return fullUrl;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `String.Replace` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8)):

> Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified Unicode
>   character or String in the current string are replaced with another
>   specified Unicode character or String.
>
> public string Replace (string oldValue, string newValue);

```
url = url.Replace("[id]", id.ToString()).Replace('[value]', value);
```